# C++ Qt Returning reference to a temporary

Tags: c++, qt

I cannot understand how to return a hashed string from function temporary memory (don't know how to correctly call it). Now, I have this code:

```
static const QString &Utils::md5(const QString &inStr)
{
    const QByteArray out = QCryptographicHash
            ::hash(inStr.toUtf8(), QCryptographicHash::Md5)
            .toHex();
    return QString(out);
}
```

But it gives warning during compilation and after I run my program it crashes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can't return a reference to a local object, even reference-to-const. I don't see a problem with returning by value, that is:

```
static QString Utils::md5(const QString &inStr) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood my error! My problem is that I need to write project on unknown for me language... so I learn it as quick as can. P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I have provided a duplicate you can read. Do a better research next time. You had the keywords.

Comment: Maybe, I have problem with English too. I understood answer above but there are in similar topics no.